# Publicly available extended summary of PhD thesis and manuscript submission

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, journals, ethics

In my country, if a PhD thesis is written in national language, the candidate must also submit an extended summary of the thesis in English, which will be deposited in a national repository and will be uploaded to the appropriate section of the university's website. This English-language document is approximately between eight and ten thousand words long, its structure is pretty similar to that of a scholarly article and can be downloaded by third parties without cost or restrictions.

I have the following two questions:

- Can a candidate submit an English-language manuscript based on the extended summary to an international scholarly journal? Should the extended summary fall in a different category with regard to prior publication than theses "published" in ProQuest ?
- A few journals publish extended abstracts and extended summaries of PhD theses as they are - these items are not peer-reviewed and the published version is essentially the same as the item submitted by the PhD candidate to the Doctoral School. This is only for increasing visibility of the original thesis and serves purely research dissemination purposes. If the candidate's extended summary is published in a journal, would it be considered a prior publication?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know some more context of what field you are in. For example, I am in mathematics and published a 4 page announcement article of my PhD thesis results in Comptes Rendus Mathematique. Although this was not quite my thesis abstract, it could be seen as such and I later published my PhD thesis as a volume in a Springer book series.

Answer (score 1):

If you submit the summary (or a substantially similar paper), you should ask the relevant people at the journal beforehand. We can't give an authoritative answer for any particular journal, let alone all of them.

Answer (score -1):

To your first query, the candidate can submit the extended summary of his thesis to a scholarly journal. And more likely of it is not to be rejected, basis the fact that it is a summary of thesis, leaving other selection criteria aside. I belong to a finance background and got the extended summary of my PhD Thesis, post submission of my thesis in an [international journal of finance](http://www.elkjournals.com/EAPJFRM.asp). Secondly, it will, in my opinion, fall in the different category with regards to the published thesis. 
For your second query, I am quite unsure of whether it will be considered a prior publication. I will check with my supervisor and will get back to you with his suggestion.